# count substrings without repeating character (total substrings with unique chars)

Tags: c++

I used acquire and release strategy in this code but it is not giving me the result. As I checked, I think it is not going in the inside loops.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    string s = "abc";
    int ans =0;
    int i= -1,j=-1;
    unordered_map<char,int> m;
    while(true){
        bool f1 = false;
        bool f2 = false;
        while(i< s.length()-1){
            //aquire
            f1 = true;
            i++;
            char ch = s[i];
            m[ch]++;
            if(m[ch]==2){
                break;
            }else{
                ans += i-j;
            }
        }
        
        while(j<i){
            //release
            f2 = true;
            j++;
            char ch = s[j];
            m[ch]--;
            if(m[ch]==1){
                ans+= i-j;
                break;
            }
        }
          
        if(f1 == false && f2 == false){
            break;
        }
    }
        
    cout<<ans;

    return 0;
}`
```

As by this code, this should give answer as  6 = a,b,c,ab,bc,abc.

Comment: Why so complicated this algorithm? Isn't number of substrings equal to the number of delimiters +1 ?

Comment: I also said without repeating characters like if the string is "abca" . The answer is a,a,abc,bc,b,c,ca,bca.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: @Nitish: `std::string::length` returns an unsigned int (size_t), which can eventually underflow cause of the -1 if the string is empty.

Comment: @Nitish In your comment of a second example above why is `a` repeated?

Comment: I said all the substrings without the repeating characters. The substrings can repeat.

Comment: Are you counting unique substrings with unique chars or total substrings with unique chars?  For example, if the input string is simple `"abab"` then are there 7 strings (a, ab, b, ba, a, ab, b) or do you filter out the duplicates and only count 4 (a, ab,b, ba) ?

Comment: total substrings with unique chars.

Comment: For `abca`, I get 9, not 8 as you show: a,
ab,
abc,
b,
bc,
bca,
c,
ca,
a

Comment: I also said without repeating characters like if the string is "abca" . The answer is a,a,abc,bc,b,c,ca,bca,ab. sorry,I left ab.

Comment: Ok, so I got it right then. I only presented the result in a different order. For counting, that shouldn't be an issue I guess?

Comment: @Nitish: Someone spend time to solve your problem, despite this is kind of grey area for this site. Could I suggest you to at least thank him with a "+1" **and** accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'd rewrite the loops a bit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

unsigned count_substr_without_repeating_chars(const std::string& s) {
    unsigned r = 0;
    
    for(unsigned f = 0; f < s.size(); ++f) {         // first char
        std::unordered_set<char> seen;
        for(unsigned l = f; l < s.size(); ++l) {     // last char
            auto[it, inserted] = seen.emplace(s[l]); // try inserting
            if(not inserted) break;        // no need to investigate this further
            ++r;
            //std::cout << std::string(&s[f], std::next(&s[l])) << '\n';
        }
    }
    return r;
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "abca";
    std::cout << count_substr_without_repeating_chars(s) << '\n'; // prints 9
}
```

An alternative could be to use a [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) for the `char`s that's already been seen instead of an `std::unordered_set<char>`. This `vector` specialization will probably require very little memory compared to the `unordered_set`.

```
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

unsigned count_substr_without_repeating_chars(const std::string& s) {
    static_assert(sizeof(char) < sizeof(int),
                  "not a good solution on this platform");
    unsigned r = 0;
    for(unsigned f = 0; f < s.size(); ++f) {         // first char
        std::vector<bool> seen(
            // make space for all char:s
            std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max() + 1
        );
        for(unsigned l = f; l < s.size(); ++l) {     // last char
            auto ch = static_cast<unsigned char>(s[l]);          
            if(seen[ch]) break; // no need to investigate this further
            seen[ch] = true;
            ++r;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Good example of structured binding. Not sure about the usage of `not` instead of `!`.

Comment: @AdrianMaire Thanks. My eyes don't like `!` any longer :-)

Comment: `max()+1` : you relay here on something very weird. Don't you? I would cast it for readability

Comment: @AdrianMaire I rely on an implicit conversion (not so weird i.m.o.). If you're on a system where `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`, there will be a compilation error (0 sized arrays are not allowed) - which would be ok, since I don't think the alternative solution would be a very good solution on such a platform. I added a `static_assert` to make that more visible.